# Load async data into the vuex store when Nuxt app loads

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, middleware

I am trialling a project in `Nuxt`.  Liking it so far except I am a little confused as to how to load data from an external async service so that it is available in `Vuex` from the very first route.

I have tried adding `middleware` on the default layout to dispatch the store action but I do not see the service being called straight away.  Only when I navigate deeper into the routes do I see the action dispatched.

I did something similar in a standard Vue project and added the `created` method to the `App.vue`.
Is there a similar way in `Nuxt`?

Answer (score 3):

What you need is called a **fetch**.

The **fetch** method, if set, is called every time before loading the component (**only for page components**). It will be called **server-side** once (on the first request to the Nuxt app) and client-side when navigating to further routes.

**Warning:** You **don't** have access of the component instance through this inside fetch because it is called **before initiating** the component.

```
async fetch({ store }) {
  await store.dispatch('your-action')
}
```

If you need parameter:

```
async fetch({ store, params }) {
  await store.dispatch('your-action', params.id)
}
```

I gave an example of id. The name of the parameter depends on the name of your page.

```
_id => params.id
_slug => parmas.slug
...
```